# Is the sequence on how we type a Sqlite query to Create a column with attributes really matters

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm new to coding android apps with Sqlite

I have three questions

I created this Sqlite table with columns with attributes like 
TEXT
NOT NULL 
UNIQUE
DEFAULT regular

Q1) I'm skeptical to know whether is there any order on how to delare attributes for a row

Q2) If I declare any row to have a default value like  will the text be still inserted even though the user inserts something in that row, if yes, then how to insert a default value if the user dosen't inset any value in a specific Row

Q3)Is my code below correct ? What I desire is the row KEY_TAGNAME to be unique, not null and to have a value  if the row doesn't get any data while a insert statement occurs for that table.

```
private static final String CREATE_TAGTABLE_SQL=
        "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE_TAG
        + " (" 
        + KEY_TAGROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + KEY_TAGNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE DEFAULT regular"
        + ");";
```

Comment: when in doubts, read the doc: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A1**: I couldn't find anything in the documentation that clearly says anything about the order of the attributes but I tried to create a couple of tables in a test database I created to check this and it seems that if you do not follow the proper order you will get a syntax error.

(tried with `create table test (key1 integer primary key autoincrement)` which works correctly but `create table test1 (key1 primary key integer autoincrement)` gives a `near "integer": syntax error:`

**A2**: You can have a default value inserted that will be put if the user does not input anything there. The keyword is `default` and you will find more info [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) on how to use it (TL;DR upon table's creation you will create the row as usual and in the end put a DEFAULT and next to it the value. Please check the link on this)

**A3** Your query is correct and will do the things you mention.